# Should I use Python for a small CRM ? If not, then is there any other platform?

Tags: python, development-environment, crm, platform

We have a new client who would like us to develop a custom CRM for their employees.

The main features they would like are:

1. Ability to save forms
2. Send reminders to employees by email and text messages
3. Basic charting capabilities
4. Automatic backup online

So as we see, saving data, and then reminding the employees are the most important functions of this CRM.

Now my main question is -- I've been meaning to learn Python since a while. I think this CRM should be doable by a person who is learning Python. I have good experience in PHP, jQuery and a little bit of .NET

So does anyone here think that I should go ahead with Python as a platform for this project ? Or should I go for any other platform, which might have features that Python won't provide me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't re-invent the wheel, if I were you. Instead I will aim to leverage one of the existing open source CRMs to build the system. A well known open source CRM is [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/). There are more available, most of them built with PHP, so your PHP experience will be useful.

Comment: We did look at the existing solutions, but all them have a million more features than we require.. BTW, could you also point me to some good tutorial on customizing SugarCRM ?

Comment: You can start at http://developers.sugarcrm.com/. SugarCRM is around for some time and they are also some books available for it. Having more features than you need isn't a bad thing. OK, the learning curve will be steeper, but you may need these features in the future for this or for a new project.